# foreach is not a member of Int

Tags: scala

Below code is throwing an error:

```
def sum(args: Int) = {
    var result = 0
    for (arg <- args) result += arg 
    result
}

error : error: value foreach is not a member of Int
       for (arg <- args) result += arg
```

Whereas if I change the argument intake its working fine

```
def sum(args: Int*) = {
    var result = 0
    for (arg <- args) result += arg 
    result
}
```

This works fine:

```
val s = sum(1, 4, 9, 16, 25)
```

Can anyone help me understand this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too basic and user has made no effort.

Comment: @flavian isn't this rather a downvote reason? Is there no duplicate available as a reason to close it?

Comment: @flavian this seems a perfectly reasonable question (and answer) to me - off-topic is nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum(args: Int) = {
  var result = 0
  for (arg <- args) result += arg 
  result
}
```

In the above code, `args` is a single `Int`. The compiler tries to translate `for (arg <- args)` to `args.foreach`, but `foreach` is not defined for an `Int`; `foreach` is a function that is defined for collections.

```
def sum(args: Int*) = {
  var result = 0
  for (arg <- args) result += arg 
  result
}
```

In the above code, `args` is an `Int*`, or a variable-length argument (or "varargs"), meaning in this case, one or more `Int`s. Varargs are translated to `Seq`s. `foreach` is defined for `Seq`, so the compiler is happy.